# IE slows down animated GIFs with more than 6-8 FPS. Is there a fix or a cross-browser alternative (except flash)?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, animation, gif, animated-gif

Honestly, until now I never noticed, but IE actually slows animated GIFs with more than 6-8 FPS (12-16ms/frame) down. For example, open this GIF in IE and in Chrome - you will see the difference:

http://netanimations.net/Moving-picture-winged-dragon-animated-gif.gif

My question is: Is there a way to fix this, let's say with a javascript? Or is there an alternative that's supported in all the major browsers? Except flash.

Edit: I know about APNG and MNG, but the support is not what one would expect.

Answer (score 7):

This is an old problem relating to how browsers implement small GIF file animation delays.

There is a better article about it here http://humpy77.deviantart.com/journal/Frame-Delay-Times-for-Animated-GIFs-240992090

A summary of that article is that: Don't use delays of 0-1 (hundredths of a second), avoid 2-5 if you like IE users. 0.06 seconds is the first cross-browser safe delay.

Alternatives include Flash, SVG, Canvas and the slightly more complicated but more cross-platform compatible method of sending a different gif based on the user agent.

This behaviour has also been changed in IE10, it will now display GIF's up to 50FPS (2 hundredths of a second) I believe this brings it up to line with other browsers.

Comment: So in other words, unless you would use flash, there is currently no way to have a fully supported fast-motion object on a site, that has all the features of an animated GIF, right? PS: Chrome was only an example, the GIF works ok also in Firefox and Opera.

Comment: Flash, SVG, or sending a different GIF file based on the user agent of the browser would all work.

Comment: Updated the answer, what I said before wasn't accurate

Comment: As far as I know, SVG has also some problems with IE - it doesn't move at all, unless there's a fix I don't know about. By the "GIF file based on the user agent" you would basically slow down the GIF manually or delete some frames and that's not exactly a good solution I would say. As I see it, flash is really the only way ... for now anyway. APNG was a nice concept, the transparency problem was also solved, but it's not widely supported - it's a shame.

Comment: I've read that article a while ago, it's really detailed. So the easiest way would be to wait for the replacement of IE8/IE9 with IE10.

Comment: Pretty much, yep. Honestly though, the difference it makes to most gifs is minimal. As you infer in your original question, the difference is hard to spot. If you set the delay to be 6hundredths of a second, the GIF will look fine on all platforms. As stated above, the reason that gif in particular looks bad is that the delay is smaller than 0.06 seconds.

Comment: Actually, it's quite weird, that there's no other worldwide accepted image based alternative for animated GIFs. No progress in 25 year (since 1987 or so). Anyway, thank you for your answers, I didn't know about IE10.

Comment: It's a shame google refuse to implement APNG, if they did that would have easily become the new standard.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight is an alternative..

Comment: Yes, it is, but I know from experience, that people do not like to install 3rd party software/plugins. Flash is a must-have in this days. It's even preinstalled on XP, if I'm not mistaking.

Comment: Silverlight is not just the competitor to Flash on web. Its core purpose is to enrich the .NET platform with mid-level graphics support. In Windows 8, Silverlight isn't supported in IE10-modern-UI (formerly Metro-style) but Adobe Flash is *pre-installed*. However, as a developer, you can consume Silverlight, DirectX and XNA libraries in .NET desktop and store-apps.